# Configure Visual Studio to use Boost::Tests for C++ command line app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, configuration, boost-test

How to properly configure Visual Studio solution to achieve:

1. Testing classes used in the application using `Boost::Test` unit tests
2. Building an executable file - the developed, command line application

---

That is what i currently have tried (basing on Google and other Stack Overflow questions):

Three projects within one solution:

- **appname-lib** (all the classes of application without the main entry
  point, `Configuration Type: Static library (.lib)`)
- **appname-app** (the
  main entry point, `Configuration Type: Application (.exe)`
- **appname-test** (only test cases, entry point is generated by
  `Boost::Test`, `Configuration Type: Application (.exe)`)

Is it a correct way? If yes please help me with the configuration of these projects:

How to make the `appname-lib` visible within other projects?

How to force building `appname-lib` during build of `appname-test` and `appname-app`?

Maybe there is a simplier / better way to achieve that?